# Is "to be" unnecessary in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Which is the correct usage here?
This

1. Final location of these holes are to be to suit at  field.

Or this

2  Final location of these holes are to suit at field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have to wait 40 minutes to post again

Comment: We will need more context to ascertain which is correct but currently I think "to suit at field" is incorrect grammar. Give me a bit more context and I'll give you a sentence that works

Comment: This sentence is a special note in an engineering drawing. This note is an instruction to the fabricator that the locations of holes shown in the drawing are just indicative only and the final ( or actual) location to be decided at work site (field) based on the actual conditions/ situations there ( which is unknown to the person who prepared this engineering drawing).

Comment: For jargon, you're on your own. If you want better English, your own verb *decided* is what's missing in the note: "Holes are to be decided (adjusted or set) to suit at field."

Comment: myspaceengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Myspace-Sample-Erection-Drawings.pdf seems to be the source. The note is -> "*" INDICATES "CUT TO SUIT AT FIELD"..This means "Parts marked with an asterisk should be  should be cut to size on site."